Accessing the content of a file inside Helm Chart
I'm trying to retrieve a secret from hashicorp vault using annotations and pass it as an env variable in the below  helm chart. The annotations write the password into a file named myconfig.env, then this file is read using the command .Files.Get , However I get an error "<.Files.Get>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.Get". how do I pass the password as an env variable inside the chart?
I have tried using the '| nindent 4" as some posts suggested but that gave the same error.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "{{ .name }}-app-auth-test"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade,test
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
    "helm.sh/weight": "0"
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
    vault.hashicorp.com/ca-cert: /ca/dev.pem
    vault.hashicorp.com/namespace: "org"
    vault.hashicorp.com/role: vault-service-role
    vault.hashicorp.com/secret-volume-path: /secrets
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-myconfig.env: path/to/secret
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-myconfig.env: |
      {{`{{- with secret "path/to/secret" }}
      {{ .Data.data.password }}
      {{- end -}}`}}
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
{{- if hasKey $.Values.default "imagePullSecrets" }}
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: {{ $.Values.default.imagePullSecrets }}
{{- end }}
  serviceAccountName: serviceAccount
  containers:
  - name: app-auth-test
    image: "{{ default $.Values.default.imageRepository $.Values.jobs.test.imageRepository }}/{{ $.Values.jobs.test.image }}"
    imagePullPolicy: {{ default $.Values.default.imagePullPolicy $.Values.jobs.test.imagePullPolicy }}
    terminationMessagePolicy: "FallbackToLogsOnError"
    command: [ "python", "scripts/validate_app_credentials.py" ]
    resources:
{{ toYaml ( default $.Values.default.resources $.Values.jobs.test.resources ) | indent 6 }}
    env:
    - name: APP_HOST
      value: {{ .hostname | quote }}
    - name: APP_PORT
      value: {{ .port | quote }}
    - name: APP_ACCOUNT_ID
      value: {{ .auth.accountId | quote }}
    - name: APP_USERNAME
      value: {{ .auth.username }}
    - name: APP_PASSWORD
      value: {{ .Files.Get "/secrets/myconfig.txt" | quote }}

Ideally, the password from the file is read and passed as the env variable.

I see other references to fields like .hostname or .port; is this inside a range loop or a with block?  In which case $.Files should work, the same way you use $.Values elsewhere.  Similarly see ingress.yaml template returns error in renderring --> nil pointer evaluating interface {}.service.

Yes, this is inside a range, all the other values are coming from the values.yaml while the file used by .Files is coming from the vault annotations.
